# How to push value into sub array without making a new entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

So I've got these two arrays:

```
resultList: { date: string, amount: number }[] = [];
dateList: { date: string, amounts: { amount: number }[] }[] = [];
```

One of them has all results, which I want to sort by dates hence the second array.
This is the code I'm using to try to achieve this:

```
this.resultList.forEach((result) => {
      let dateFound: boolean = false;
      this.dateList.forEach((date) => {
        if (result.date === date.date) {
          dateFound = true;
          return;
        }
      });
      if (dateFound == false) {
        //create new date entry in dateList
        this.dateList.push({date: result.date, amounts: []});
      }
      //find that date entry and push a value to it's sub array called amounts
      this.dateList.find((dates) => {
        return dates.date == result.date
      }).amounts.push({
        amount: result.amount
      });
    });
```

OUTPUT if you have 3 results of the same date

```
[
  {date: '2018-03-21', amounts: [{amount: 1}]},
  {date: '2018-03-21', amounts: [{amount: 1},{amount: 43}]},
  {date: '2018-03-21', amounts: [{amount: 1},{amount: 43}, {amount: 55}]}
]
```

Desired OUTPUT if you have 3 results of the same date

```
[
  {date: '2018-03-21', amounts: [{amount: 1},{amount: 43}, {amount: 55}]}
]
```

Comment: Can you post a valid the input data?

Comment: `if using lodash then _.groupBy else use lodash`

Comment: @georg hehehe yes or yes!

Comment: For me that code seems to work...

Comment: @H.B. That's the weird thing, I copied this code from another project where I did the same thing and it works there. So I thought I may be doing something wrong or maybe find doesn't work that way or whatever.

Comment: @georg I'm sorry but I don't know what you're talking about. I do not know those terms.

Comment: `lodash` a utility library which includes a `groupBy` function, i.e. exactly what you are doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) your data into an object with the unique dates as the keys and the amounts as the value for each key, and then [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) them into the structure for your desired output, like so:

```js
var data = [
  {date: '2018-03-21', amount: 1},
  {date: '2018-03-21', amount: 43},
  {date: '2018-03-21', amount: 41},
  {date: '2018-03-22', amount: 18},
  {date: '2018-03-23', amount: 25},
  {date: '2018-03-24', amount: 15},
  {date: '2018-03-24', amount: 25},
];

// reduce to single object with unique dates as keys, collection of amounts as values
var dateMap = data.reduce((res, curr) => {
  // if the date has not been added already
  if (!res[curr.date]) {
    // create it on the result object
    res[curr.date] = []
  }
  // push the amount into the array for the date
  res[curr.date].push({amount: curr.amount});
  return res;
}, {});

// map each key of dateMap to an object matching the desired output format
var dateList = Object.keys(dateMap).map(key => {
  return {date: key, amounts: dateMap[key]};
});

console.log(dateList);
```

Comment: Works very neatly, thanks!
Do you know perhaps why my approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I added an `else` clause to your if condition and remove the `.find()` part:

```
if (dateFound == false) {
  //create new date entry in dateList
  this.dateList.push({date: result.date, amounts: []});
} else {
  for (let d of this.dateList) {
    if (d.date == result.date) {
      d.amounts.push({amount: result.amount})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now. This would really be my first approach in this type of stuff but javascript really threw me off on this one.

Comment: glad to hear that your problem is solved :) Happens to all of us

Comment: This maintains the original `O(n^2)` time complexity, though

Comment: And I think it should be `this.dateList.push({date: result.date, amounts: result.amount})` - otherwise you don't get the amount for the first occurrence of each unique date

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). For each date create an object with the `amounts` attribute, and fill it with the amount values from the same date. Then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back to an array:

```js
const data = [{"date":"2018-03-21","amount":1},{"date":"2018-03-21","amount":43},{"date":"2018-03-21","amount":41},{"date":"2018-03-22","amount":18},{"date":"2018-03-23","amount":25},{"date":"2018-03-24","amount":15},{"date":"2018-03-24","amount":25}];

const result = [...data
  .reduce((r, o) => {
    const { date, amount } = o;
  
    r.has(date) || r.set(date, { 
      date, 
      amounts: [] 
    });
    
    r.get(date).amounts.push({ amount });
    
    return r;
  }, new Map())
  .values()
];

console.log(result);
```